# RecyclerView item loses padding on small screen but not large

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-popupwindow

I'm experiencing unusual behaviour with my RecyclerView which is displayed inside a PopupWindow. On my large screen device (Galaxy Note 10.1), it displays fine immediately:

[image: Large Screen]

However, on my two smaller screen devices (Nexus 6P and Galaxy Note 8), the padding is gone at first (sorry about the zoom-level/size, the padding should be clear) and there's extra white space below the RecyclerView:

[image: Small screen 1]

But when I "activate" the item somehow, such as long pressing a 'document' item or normal-clicking a 'category' item (clicking a 'category' item shows or hides its document children items), the padding returns to what it should be:

[image: Small screen 2]

I've had this happen with Spinners when opening one for the second time, and the hack-fix for that is to re-initialize the adapter when closing the adapter, so it appears to display correctly every time it's opened, instead of just the first.

I don't have different resource files for small and large screens for this layout and I've worked with custom RecyclerView adapters quite a bit. I'm wondering if it's due to it being in a PopupWindow, if that somehow affects it.

Here's where I init the RecyclerView and PopupWindow:

```
    final RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, null, false);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new DomaLinearLayoutManager(activity));
    rv.setAdapter(new DocumentsAdapter(activity, docCategories));

    dropdownTV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(rv, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false);
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popupWindow.setContentView(rv);
            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(dropdownTV, -5, 0);
        }
    });
```

The onBindViewHolder method:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DocumentsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {      
        if (items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()) instanceof DocumentsCategory) {
            TextUtils.setTextAppearance(activity, holder.nameTV, R.style.regularTextLargeBold);
            holder.nameTV.setPadding(activity.dpToPx(12), activity.dpToPx(12), activity.dpToPx(5), activity.dpToPx(5));
            holder.nameTV.setText(ViewUtils.paintTextEnd(activity, "",
                ((DocumentsCategory) items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())).getName(), R.color.domacare_blue, true));
        } else { //is a document
            holder.nameTV.setPadding(activity.dpToPx(12), activity.dpToPx(12), activity.dpToPx(12), activity.dpToPx(12));
            holder.nameTV.setText(((Document) items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())).getProperName());
            holder.nameTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.holo_dark_green));
        }

        holder.nameTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.action_bar_selector);
        holder.nameTV.setSingleLine(false);

        if (items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()) instanceof DocumentsCategory || holder.getAdapterPosition() == items.size() - 1) {
            holder.divider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.divider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

And the dropdown layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        style="@style/blueTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_blue_to_accent_blue"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Updated below with xml files:

recyclerview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    style="@style/MyListView"/>
```

spinner_dropdown_tv.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/ll"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    style="@style/blueTextMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_my_blue_to_accent_blue"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxWidth="300dp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="" />
    <View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyListView" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
  <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@null</item>
  <item name="android:background">@color/gray_tasklist</item>
  <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
  <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
  <item name="android:fadingEdge">none</item>
  <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
  <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">false</item>
  <item name="android:descendantFocusability">blocksDescendants</item>
  <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_blue</item>
  <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
  <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarSize">3dp</item>
</style>

<style name="blueTextMedium" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
  <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_blue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Post your code also.

Comment: Hi the layout xml file is in layout folder only right, not in any specific resolution

Comment: Post what's in the style, and also post the layout of recyclerview

Comment: Both layout files (recyclerview and spinner_dropdown_tv) are only in the layout folder. I added those xml files and my styles that are used.

Comment: @SFitz were you able to fix this issue.

Comment: For anyone who is facing this issue, checkout this link. Maybe helpful to you https://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg09595.html